# how to remove constant line from point line series?

Tags: lightningchart

I'm using constant lines to show a particular event for the graph and now I want to remove that particular event. I'm using `constantline.dispose` method but It's not working properly.  lines are not getting removed after calling `dispose` function.

Answer (score 0):

`ConstantLine.dispose()` should do the trick, and seems to work in the official interactive examples gallery (LCJS v.3.4.0).

If it is not working for you, please add some example code or pictures & description of desired and actual behaviours.